# Where can I find good documentation on ExtJS's templates?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm attempting to learn Sencha Touch (and Ext JS, being more of a jquery guy), and I'm struggling a bit with the documentation.

For example, I'm trying to figure out how to write templates, but I've found the documentation to be very sparse. For example, [this page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Template) tells me how to instantiate a template, but not what the syntax looks like and how to write them. I found a [couple](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Getting_Started_with_Templates) [tutorials](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Utilizing_Format_Features_of_Templates) on their site, but I'm really looking for a page that tells me what the language looks like, something like [Django's template page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

Does anyone know if something like that exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Ext.XTemplate](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.XTemplate) class and expand the XTemplate( Mixed config ) method to view a good description on how to use a XTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

[sencha person] We just posted a pretty awesome intro screencast (2 part). This is the [first part of the xTemplate screencast](http://www.vimeo.com/16289757)